# Can I put a Portuguese address on a UK driving license?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, portuguese-citizens

Can I put a Portuguese address on a UK driving license?

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/driving-in-portugal-non-pt-car-non-pt-drivers-license/10522#10522

Answer (score 3):

[No, you can't](https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence). The DVLA will only take UK addresses, and you must be UK resident to update your UK license to your current address.

As Adam Millerchip points out in the comments, and I hadn't realised, NI has a separate licensing authority (the DVA) but, in any case, they [have the same rules](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/keeping-your-driving-licence-date).

Comment: For completeness, the DVLA only handles GB licences. Same situation in NI though: https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/keeping-your-driving-licence-date

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: Thank you. I hadn't realised that Northern Ireland had a separate agency. I have updated the answer accordingly.