# Driving in Portugal: Non-PT car / Non-PT Drivers License

Tags: portugal

Are there any odd rules or laws in Portugal regarding driving with a non-Portuguese (but EU) drivers license?

Also, are there any important rules/laws regarding driving a non-Portuguese car (with non-PT, but EU license plates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to drive a car with Portuguese registration and you have the documents to prove you are allowed (owner of the car or you have document showing the owner allows you, like a signed declaration) then everything is alright.

But if you have a local (Portuguese) drivers license and you are driving a foreign car (UK license plates, for example) then you might have a big problem. The traffic police might make an issue that the car is not imported if you are a Portuguese citizen with a Portuguese driver's license. They could confiscate your documents and issue a penalty for you to pay.

Keep in mind a lot of car traffic tickets issued by the police are very much disputable and my personal experience is that they tend to write tickets without any underlying legal basis. My explanation is that they do it because most of the people would not bother to dispute their tickets. In most cases, if you feel it is not right, you would be right. Research, ask for help and dispute!

Anyway, I hope that you find this useful in any way. Boa Sorte!